# How to match a pattern in String where string to match is "operands":["10000"]

Tags: java, regex

I have a long json string, `"attributeName":"Loc ID"},"operands":["10000"]}],"frequency":{"type":"` This is just some part of it, i just want to match this pattern `"operands":["10000"]` in the given string.

I have already tried using

`string.replace("\"operands\":[\"10000\"]","\"operands\":[\"20000\"]")`

Even tried regex `"\"operands\":[\"\\d+\"]"`

I am using JAVA to get the desired result.

Comment: Use a json parser not regex.

Comment: You should be using a JSON parser here, not a regex.

Comment: `[` and `]` have special meaning in regex, they must be escaped (quoted) to be matched (two backslashes) - [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this expression,

```
"operands"\\s*:\\s*\\[\\s*"(\\d*)"\\s*\\]
```

and a replacement of,

```
"operands":["20000"]
```

might work just OK.

---

If there is no additional space,

```
\"operands\":\\[\"(\\d*)\"\\]
```

might work just fine.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    final String regex = "\"operands\"\\s*:\\s*\\[\\s*\"\\s*(\\d*)\\s*\"\\s*\\]";
    final String string = "\"attributeName\":\"Loc ID\"},\"operands\":[\"10000\"]}],\"frequency\":{\"type\":\"\n"
         + "\"attributeName\":\"Loc ID\"},\"operands\":[ \" 10000 \" ]}],\"frequency\":{\"type\":\"";
    final String subst = "\"operands\":[\"20000\"]";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

    System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
"attributeName":"Loc ID"},"operands":["20000"]}],"frequency":{"type":"
"attributeName":"Loc ID"},"operands":["20000"]}],"frequency":{"type":"
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WzcmYD/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/WzcmYD/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks but String doesn't have any whitespace character

Comment: Still no success.. its not matching yet.. I tried escaping : as well ```"\"operands\"\\:\\[\"\\d*\"\\]"``` and ```"\"operands\"\\:\\[\"(\\d*)\"\\]"```

Comment: Actually this worked for me ```"\"operands\":\\[\"(\\+?\\d+)\"\\]"```